# Extract groups of characters in a string

Tags: java

I have a string `123456789`
I also have a bunch of numbers (identities, if you will) such as

```
2 1 1 1 2 2
2 1 1 1 3 1
2 1 1 2 1 2
2 1 1 2 2 1
2 1 1 3 1 1
```

The idea is, these numbers specify the groups of digits that should be extracted from the string (left to right order, if that matters). Therefore, a number like `2 3 2 1 1` means `Output the first 2 characters, then the next 3 characters, then the next 2 characters, then the next 1 character, then finally the last 1 character remaining.`So as examples,
`2 1 1 1 2 2` should output `12 3 4 5 67 89`
`2 1 1 1 3 1` should output `12 3 4 5 678 9`
`2 1 1 2 1 2` should output `12 3 4 56 7 89`
`2 1 1 2 2 1` should output `12 3 4 56 78 9`
`2 1 1 3 1 1` should output `12 3 4 567 8 9`

I tried working with the method `charAt()` but it would seem that's just not for me

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mine = "123456789";
    System.out.println(mine.charAt(2)+"\t"+mine.charAt(1)+"\t"+
    mine.charAt(1)+"\t"+mine.charAt(1)+"\t"+mine.charAt(2)
    +"\t"+mine.charAt(2));
}
```

The above gives an unwanted output

```
3   2   2   2   3   3
```

How do I solve this rather tricky (for me) issue ?

Comment: Note that `charAt()` returns a **single** character. But in many cases, you need 2 or more characters. Check out `substring()` to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given a simple trial on it. Does below give you some help?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] identitiesBunch = new int[][] { 
        {2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2},
        {2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1},
        {2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2},
        {2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1},
        {2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1} 
    };

    String mine = "123456789";
    char[] numbers = mine.toCharArray();

    int index = 0;
    for (int[] identities: identitiesBunch) {
        for (int id: identities ) {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < id; i++)
                System.out.print(numbers[index++]);
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        index = 0;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work for you.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String identities = "2 1 1 1 3 1";

        String stringToBreakApart = "123456789";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int currentPosition = 0;

        for(String identityString : identities.split(" ")){
            int identity = Integer.parseInt(identityString);

            sb.append(stringToBreakApart, currentPosition, currentPosition += identity);
            sb.append(" ");

        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
```